# OpenSSL Padding Oracle vulnerability (CVE-2016-2107) + Nginx

Tags: nginx, openssl, ubuntu-14.04

I was trying [Qualys SSL Labs test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html) and It told me that the server is vulnerable to `OpenSSL Padding Oracle vulnerability (CVE-2016-2107)`. I googled around on how to fix this, and although the OpenSSL version installed on my system (Ubuntu 14.04) should be patched for that according to this [link](https://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-2959-1/)  I was still getting this error.

I tried upgrading OpenSSL but it was already the newest version, so I installed manually a newer version following the instructions [here](http://www.miguelvallejo.com/updating-to-openssl-1-0-2g-on-ubuntu-server-12-04-14-04-lts-to-stop-cve-2016-0800-drown-attack/) which went fine, but that didn't fix anything. Looking at the info from Nginx, It seems it still runs with the previous version:

```
nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.10.2
built with OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014 (running with OpenSSL 1.0.2g-fips 1 Mar 2016)
```

while OpenSSL has clearly been updated:

```
openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2j 26 Sep 2016
```

Any idea how to get all this sorted out?

Note that yes, I did restart Nginx, I even tried `sudo service nginx upgrade` and even rebooted the server.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: Be careful of the Server Fault folks. My experience has been they are mostly assholes. That's kind of why I suggest [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). The [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) folks are incredibly helpful, and you usually don't get the attitude from Server Fault.

Comment: eheheh thanks for the heads up, gonna post on U&L as soon as the 40min limit is gone!